# Problems with eclipse and maven war plugin overlay

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-war-plugin

I have a project where I am replacing out the web.xml and other files using a war overlay in maven. Everything works great and then I try to import into eclipse and have all kinds of problems.

To start with I use mvn eclipse:eclipse to generate my Eclipse files. This works but the imported project does not contain the Dynamic Web facet.

Once the Dynamic Web facet (version 2.5) is added, the project still recognizes the deployment descriptor as 2.4 and gives me errors anyway even though it is;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
```

Has anyone struggled through this type of thing before?

Comment: I think you'd be better off *not* using the Maven Eclipse plugin, but rather use [m2e](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/). Which version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: oops wrong question, this still isn't working I am using m2e and I am using m2e-wtp. It works when I turn off binding and extensions validation.